# El significado de "expedientes" en "podrás conocer el estado de tramitación de tus expedientes correspondientes a los procedimientos"

Tags: significado

Quisiera confirmar si "expedientes" en "[podrás conocer el estado de tramitación de tus expedientes correspondientes a los procedimientos cuya tramitación se haya iniciado con posterioridad a 1-1-2010, así como realizar los trámites y las consultas previstas](https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/mi-area-personal.html)" significa "conjunto de todos los papeles correspondientes a un asunto o negocio.". ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El "**Expediente**" es un documento en curso que lleva consigo un conjunto de datos y notas requeridos en su momento y necesarios para abrir o comenzar con la tramitación del mismo, que sirven de antecedente y fundamento a fin de resolverlo administrativamente. Hasta su resolución, el expediente, pasará por distintas fases en las cuales se estudiará el caso por parte de la administración española. Normalmente cuando se habla de "*expediente en tramite*", se refiere a la primera fase del proceso administrativo y puede, según los casos y dependiendo de los tramites necesarios, tomar un plazo considerable de tiempo, tres, seis o incluso más meses para la resolución del mismo.

En este sentido aquí, "**expediente**" significa aquel conjunto de documentos que te solicitaron y que ahora se encuentran en curso. El enlace señala, en este caso, que podrás consultar o conocer la fase de tramitación o estado en el que este o estos se encuentran, en el caso de que tengas varios expedientes abiertos.

**P.D.** Creo que también es posible obtener información del estado de tramitación de un expediente, llamando al número de teléfono 902 02 22 22.

Comment: Hola, Diego, muchas gracias de verdad por su ayuda, como siempre ~ Digo "siempre" por varias razones, y una de ellas es porque usted siempre intenta a ayudarme a entender un término con mucho detalle y al mismo tiempo fácil de entender. Y esto requiere mucha energía y mucho tiempo de su parte para poder dar unas explicaciones tan "perfectas". Ojalá pudiera recompensarle de alguna manera. Así que muchas gracias otra vez ~

Comment: Gracias a ti por apreciarlo, aunque siempre hay otras personas que consideran que es fácil encontrar las respuestas en internet a este tipo de cuestiones. Me refiero a aquellos que han cerrado esta pregunta por que consideran que no tiene esfuerzo. ¡Cuídate!

Comment: Como dicen por ahí: así es la vida ...